Camping well pump
I have some land and a camper, I have been hauling in water which is a pain. I do have a shallow well that is about 25 feet down into the ground. I have a pump, so I am curious if I need the pressure tank or I can run it without it? The only thing I would use it for is to fill a basin I use to fill my camper for shower water. So I would run it, fill the 2500 gallon basin and then shut it off, I would only need to do this a couple times a year.

You could use a shallow well pump and just turn it on and off as needed. Of course use a backflow preventer.

Do keep in mind that shallow well water may need extra...help to deal with contamination

That seems fine, you only need a pressure tank when your pump is operated using a pressure switch.
If it is operated manually or using a float switch there's no need for a pressure tank.

We all know what happens when something like is operated manually all the time.

If it's only being done  twice a year, manual is probably ok.  but if more often  there will be an incentive to install a (water level operated) float  switch on the cistern
